# regex that matches URL to image than replaces characters

Tags: regex

I have rewrite rules in an xml file this this notation

```
<rule>
<from></from>
<forward></forward>
</rule>
```

in the from node, I am looking to match a URL that has an image extension at the end and dash `"-"` characters in the name. If that matches, in the forward node I would like to replace the dash `"-"` characters with underscore characters `"_"`

for example

`longUrl/test-image.jpg` would go to `longUrl/test_image.jpg`

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like that on top of your .htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)(\-|%2D)(.*)$ /$1_$3
```

Comment: Is there a way to check for all types of images? i.e png, jpg, gif etc

Answer (score 0):

Replace this:

```
<from>([^<>]*)-([^/<>]*)\.(jpg|gif)</from>
```

with:

```
<from>$1_$2.$3</from>
```

That does one hyphen, so repeat as long as it matches